# Matching the page number in link

Tags: javascript, match

I keep trying to match the page number, but all I'm getting is undefined. What am I doing wrong?

```
var currentLink = "page_number=1";
var whatPage = currentLink.match(/page_number=([1-9])/g);
console.log(whatPage[1]);
```

Comment: If you're trying to get parameter values from a URL, rather than writing an individual RegEx for each and every expected parameter, consider using something like [`searchParams`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/979995/2026606) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using the `/g` flag, which will return an array of *all* matches to that regular expression in the string (disregarding capture groups - they aren't visible in the output with `/g`) - for example, if the input was `page_number=1,page_number=2` it would result in `page_number=2`.

```js
var currentLink = "page_number=1,page_number=2";
var whatPage = currentLink.match(/page_number=([1-9])/g);
console.log(whatPage[1]);
```

To use the capturing group of the only match, just remove the global flag:

```js
var currentLink = "page_number=1";
var whatPage = currentLink.match(/page_number=([1-9])/);
console.log(whatPage[1]);
```

Comment: It's worth noting that unless you know the page number is strictly 1-9, then you may want to append the `+` symbol to the end of your regex (i.e. `currentLink.match(/page_number=([1-9]+)/);` to cover any number of digits.

Answer (score 0):

A regex is likely overkill here. Why not just use [split()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) like this:

```
var whatPage = currentLink.split('=')[1];
```

However, if a regex is necessary, you could utilize:

```
var whatPage =  currentLink.match(/page_number=([1-9]+)/);
console.log(whatPage[1]);
```

Note, I added the `+` symbol in the case that your page number isn't strictly within the range of 1-9.

Comment: Because there's actually a lot more stuff in the link than the example I'm posting here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
var currentLink = "page_number=1";
var whatPage = currentLink.match(/[1-9]+/);  
 console.log(whatPage[0]);
```